# Unix search ignore caps

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I want to search for a specific file by name in Solaris. 
But I don't know whether the file has caps in the name or not, so I want to ignore the caps.

If i use:

find . -name 'word'

it won't find me file that is named WoRd.
I know I have to use -i somehow, but I just can't manage to find the correct syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: Try the Unix SO site, there is an answer there http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32155/find-command-how-to-ignore-case Also, google is your friend - there are many resources that offer code samples for most unix commands :-)

Comment: Since you're using solaris, -iname may not be available I'll provide an answer with the grep command

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one. It will be solved your problem

```
$find . -iname 'word'
```

Where i for ignore case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try this, -type f matches files only, you were correct to assume using the -i flag

```
  find . -type f -print | grep -i "word"
```

Also check out this answer that goes deeper: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40766/help-understanding-find-syntax-on-solaris

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.

Any idea why it finds my file named "word" when I use this:

find . -type f -print | grep -i "wor*"  - WORKS 

And it does NOT find it when I use:
find . -type f -print | grep -i "*ord"  - DOES NOT WORK

Comment: Great, glad it helped @korodani! please accept the answer

Comment: For your other question, try one of these variants "/*ord" or "**ord" - it depends on the system and how they implement wildcard searches in the regex

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I accepted your answer but because I'm a new member, the vote won't be seen just yet.